# SAP: Discover available web services through a web service call?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, sap-basis, netweaver

Sorry for my ignorance on SAP applications here, this is outside of my wheelhouse a bit and I'm trying to adjust.

As anyone who has worked with SAP applications know, there's at least a dozen ways to do anything in the system... which is both good and bad.  For what I'm trying to do (consolidate lists of security "items of interest"), it's mostly bad.

We have multiple completely separate SAP instances from various M&A's over quite a long time, and I am trying to find a common way to extract table information (user data and the like) from all of them without installing anything into the system itself.  Consuming Web services seem to be the "right" way to do this.

At the end of the day, I'd like to pull data from tables like `USR02` and compare them against all these instances, looking for commonalities and near-misses that we'll have to investigate further.

What I'd like to know is if there is an SAP web service that I can rely on to tell me what web services are available on the NetWeaver platform that I'm connecting to... or, failing that, a "default" web service that I can use to collect table information from whatever SAP table I want (that I have access to, naturally).

When I go to the WebService port in a browser, I get a 404, so I know it's listening... but there doesn't seem to be a directory listing, and I don't know how to find what I'm looking for... and SAP documentation has not been particularly helpful in this regard.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: web services are not automatically available on every system. You'll have more luck using RFC, for instance with either the .Net Connector or the Java Connector. I've used the .Net Connector with Powershell to execute RFC capable function modules. You'd need a function module that can read table data and return it, like RFC_READ_TABLE. Another way would be to extract the tables with an extractor, usually commercial. Some ETL tools have extractors, Pentaho PDI (formerly known as Kettle) has a pretty generic one for free, Talend (the paid edition) has one too.

Comment: The .Net connector was discontinued 5 years ago, doesn't look like it works with more modern frameworks (like anything that references .NET Standard)... and we aren't a Java shop.  Blech... I've worked with Pentaho before, I'll check that out, thanks.

Comment: .Net Connector isn't discontinued, just the old version is (that would be useless with Powershell anyway). The current Version 3 is still active. http://service.sap.com/connectors . Pentaho works too, the SAPInput step is just a bit cumbersome to use.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek are you sure about that?  Even on the link you sent me, it says support for v3.0 ends on July 31st, 2018.  It only seems to work on older versions of .NET too (I had problems with 4.6.2)

Comment: that only seems to be valid for the .Net 2.0 version. See note 856863, which mentions support for .Net Connector for .Net 4.0 until end of 2020.